# How is critical damage calculated?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

Based on experience in other games I'd expect it to work one of two ways:

Crit = ( Damage + ( Damage * Bonus damage percent)) * (2 + critical damage percent)

**or**

Crit = Damage * (2 + critical damage percent + Bonus damage percent)

If it works the first way, then % crit chance, % damage, and % crit damage are all multiplicatively more useful together, and it behooves you to get some of each. If it works the second way, then everything is simply a percentage increase of your base damage, and relatively interchangeable.

Other orders of operations tend to be counterintuitive, but are not unheard of.

The Amalur wiki currently being one that speaks in general terms instead of hard math, does anyone know the exact order of operations?

Comment: I don't know the formula, but I have seen Blacksmithing components that increase critical hit damage by a percentage so that should be taken into account.

Comment: @Adeese you're looking too hard - every piece of Finesse gear in the game has bonus critical damage.

Comment: @RavenDreamer there are also gems that have +crit chance

Comment: I wonder where your formulas come from. I'm not saying they're wrong, just that they may be biasing the thoughts of those reading the question to try to force the answer into one of those two boxes.

Comment: This is a hard question because of the relative ambiguities of the system in question and I don't know that anyone can readily provide much more than some speculative inference, let alone concrete answers. There's likely some randomness in damage calculation multiplying base damage and the unseen enemy defense and resistances which crit calculation may ignore or not as well as factoring in buff/debuffs applied. Maybe the enemy's current health percentage has some bearing too. I don't think it will be simple to give you a hard formula, but I would love to know it myself.

Answer (score 1):

**Crit: (Random(MinAtk, MaxAtk) * Weapon Damage Multiplier) * (2 + Critical Damage Percent)**

use this one if you want dynamic value damage..

Comment: Do you have a source link for this?

Comment: This is what I would assume, except the 2 might be a 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

It works different in different games and probably depends on your stats and gear(sword,gun ect.).

It happens randomly or is activated by certain events in the game.

If I had to choose from your examples, I think that your:

**Crit: ( Damage + ( Damage * Bonus damage percent)) * (2 + critical damage percent)**

Is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of critical hit damage multiplier for most rpgs is as follows:

```
 Critical Hit Damage Multiplier = (Base Damage Bonus on Critical Hit + Critical Hit Bonus A + Critical Hit Bonus B + ... Critical Hit Bonus Z)
```

Some combat systems also allow for flat bonuses on critical hit. I have not seen any flat bonuses to critical hit damage in KoA, only percentage based bonuses.

To answer your question more directly: **Critical Hit Damage bonuses are additive with each other, but multiplied to the base damage done on hit.** The example box shows how crit damage multipliers work in KoA. I can't tell you the base critical strike damage multiplier for sure off the top of my head, but I'm extremely confident that it is 200%, as this is the current standard in rpgs (though it could be 150%, this is the second most common value). To explain why crit damage is added and not multiplied, I'll use an example set of armor and weapons. For a set of seven items (helmet,chest,legs,boots,gloves,weapon1,weapon2) all having a +15% bonus to Critical Hit Damage:

Using additive bonuses you would deal 2.00*(1.15*7) times crit damage; 305% total damage.

Using multiplicative bonuses you would deal 2.00*(1.15^7) times crit damage; 532% total damage.
If the crit damage were 30% per piece instead, you would be dealing 1255% crit damage. It gets more ridiculous as you go up from there.

Multiplicative multipliers are generally rare in rpgs because of exponential scaling. You do see them in games, often in the form of temporary but powerful buffs. But these are usually multipliers to total damage done, not critical hit damage.

Edit: For clarification, the formula for damage done on a crit is simply:

```
 [on crit: (Weapon or Ability Damage Dealt on Hit * Critical Hit Damage Multiplier)]
```

Comment: You're making a guess, here.  While this might be true in the *general* case, we're looking for *specific* information for the game.

Comment: True, my statement was general and not specific to this game. To that end, I used a save editor to mod a new save and did testing in combat with a consistent damage sword, dagger, and bow with no bonuses from armor/skills/fate cards. They consistently crit for 150% damage. I saw no inherent bonus to crit damage from weapon type (like one might expect on daggers). 

Adding on a 30% crit bonus to all weapons and armor, I found that I was still critting consistently for 150%. But stealth attacks were doing variably but significantly more damage, up to 4x as much damage. So it appears exponential.

Comment: I'll add that I tested on the latest PC version, downloaded via Steam.

Comment: The additive bonus formula for the multiplier should be 2 + 0.15*7 = 3.05. The one you have comes out to 2*(1.15*7) = 16.1.

Comment: If you did some testing, add that to your answer. You don't get any credit for stuff in comments.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've gathered on this thread alone, with all elements considered, I'd say it's along these lines:

```
Crit Dmg = ((weapon dmg*(1+x%))*(2+y%))-d

X = weapon modifier % in decimal format
Y = total gear modifier % in decimal format
D = defense of person/mob attacked
```

Keep in mind, I don't actually play, but this is my idea of how it works based upon the answers below. If you could give me three example setups, with average damage for both the weapon, and dealt, I could formulate something more precise.

Comment: So, this is more speculation, based on a bunch of speculative answers that have already been downvoted?

Comment: a little, again, solid numbers would help formulate a more solid equation. Most of this theory comes from other games I have played with similar if not identical damage calculations, so I may not be far off. I appologise if this seems useless, I'm just trying to help